# Actual usage of the word "Dryly"

Tags: word-usage

I heard this word before in a variety of sentences.

In my book, it was written

> "I don't know", she said dryly.

From internet sources, I got to know that this word is used when we are being funny but actually are serious. I can't imagine that. Could someone please give me a relevant conceivable example so that I can relate ?

Note: dryly = drily

Comment: At its simplest, "dryly" simply means "without emotion" or "in a monotone" -- speaking without any tone-based clues as to the meaning behind the words.

Comment: And yes, that solved my problem! I can imagine now...

Comment: "I need more moisturizer," she said dryly.

Comment: @Moyli "Very droll," I said drolly.

Comment: dryly: **In a matter-of-fact** or ironically humorous way. Note the **or**. It does not have to be funny. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/dryly

Comment: @Fattie , I consulted a dictionary, I didn't find anything suitable and helpful there so I came here!

Comment: @Fattie You mean sister-site **ELL** [ell.se]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> From internet sources, I got to know that this word is used when we are being funny but actually are serious.

I think the main point is that you are missing something very important: the person says something that *is* funny, but they *say* it in a way that makes it sound serious.

It's not about whether what they say is funny or not, but about *how* they say it, or the *delivery*.

> I can't imagine that.

Imagine someone tells you that they ate rice with a spoon, and you pretend to be very serious when you tell them *I prefer my rice with vegetables*.
That could be seen as dry humor.

Comment: cf. Mark Twain, the master of dry one-liners.

Comment: But seriously, *dryly* doesn't **have** to be funny. That's a secondary meaning. The primary meaning is "without emotion," "stoically," &hellip;

Comment: When you say something "dryly" it has no connection at, all, with humor.  It's just totally unrelated.   {Sure ... ***any adjective*** can be used with "humor". Colorful humor, acidic humor, local humor, fast humor, slow humor, etc.  *As with any adjective and any subject, whatsoever.* So what?}  "Dryly" means "dryly". It could hardly be a simpler word.  English learners can glance in a dictionary for the meaning.  The example sentence, ""I don't know", she said dryly." is incredibly straightforward.  (It is utterly, totally, unrelated to "humor".)

Answer (score 12):

**dry**  adv. dry′ly, dri′ly  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/dry)

- Devoid of bias or personal concern: 'presented a dry critique'

  a. Lacking tenderness, warmth, or involvement; severe: 'The actor
  gave a dry reading of the lines'.
  b. Matter-of-fact or indifferent in manner: 'rattled off the facts in a dry mechanical tone'.

  13. Wearisome; dull: 'a dry lecture filled with trivial details'.
  14. Humorous in an understated or unemotional way: 'dry wit'.

Comment: This! (14) is the intended meaning. In German, the word *trocken* is used the same ways (as opposite of wet, and in sense of (14)).

Comment: @Fattie bit of a useless comment, but showing interconnections between related languages may shed more light onto the answer.